# PHP Form adding blank Rows in DB

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've been working with this Form since a while, and i cant figure out why it adds blanks rows in some entries. I've been trying to replicate the bug with no success. Any idea?

HTML Form:

```
<form action="connect.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="alert('Hemos recibido correctamente tu petición, muchas gracias.')">
    <p id="form_title">COMPLETA TUS DATOS Y ENVIA ESTA SOLICITUD
        <br>A LAS AUTORIDADES</p>
    <label></label>
    <input class="field" name="user_name" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Nombre:">
    <label></label>
    <input class="field" name="user_last" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Apellido:">
    <label></label>
    <input class="field" name="pais" type="text" required="required" placeholder="País:">
    <label></label>
    <input class="field" name="user_email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="Email">
    <label></label>
    <input class="field" name="tel" type="number" required="required" placeholder="Teléfono (Código de país y área)">
    <div id="masinfo" style="width: 156px;">    <a href="http://www.ficargentina.org/images/stories/Documentos/publicidad_punto_de_venta.pdf" target="_blank"><p>Más Información</p></a>

    </div>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
</div>
```

PHP Connect & Post script:

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'fic01_alto');
define('DB_USER', 'fic01_alto');
define('DB_PASSWORD','*****');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

$value1 = $_POST ['user_name'];
$value2 = $_POST ['user_last'];
$value3 = $_POST ['pais'];
$value4 = $_POST ['tel'];
$value5 = $_POST ['user_email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO registros VALUES ('', '$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Cant use' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error ());
}

mysql_close();

if($value1 !=''&& $value2 !=''&& $value3 !=''&& $value4 !=''&& $value5 !=''){
    header("Location: index.html");
    exit();
}


?>
<h2>Gracias!, hemos recibido su firma. Ahora, será redirigido.</h2>
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Blank rows for which entry and are you making sure that all fields aren't left empty? That may explain it.

Comment: you don't check, so i could just hit enter and bang blank rows

Comment: @Dagon Couldn't he just wrap his query in an if ($value1 !== NULL){ . . .

Comment: All fields are "required", so it dont let you hit enter and submit!

Comment: your browser may not, my bot cares not. never trust client side technology

Comment: I don't see where you're preventing the user from submitting the form if the fields are blank.
As a side note, you're checking that you can select the database AFTER you already use it by running a query. That's just odd to me.